# ionic - Transformar imagem de base64 para JPG

Tags: node.js, ionic, base64, ionic4

Estou fazendo um app e preciso enviar uma imagem para uma api. Porém eu tenho a imagem apenas em base64 e preciso dela em jpg. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como faço isso?

```
  public sendOnePhoto(photo: any) {
    const body = { file: photo, email: this.storage.getItem('access') };
    const data: Observable<any> = this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/picture/upload`, body);
    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, você precisa realmente enviar essa imagem em formato jpg para o servidor?

Pois existem três formas mais comuns de upload de imagem para o servidor, são elas:

1. Enviar o base64 da imagem dentro de um parâmetro da sua requisição http, e quando ela chegar no servidor você lê esse base64 e salva como uma imagem no formato jpg.
2. Converter o base64 para blob, adicionar o blob no body da sua requisição http e enviar. Quando o blob chegar no servidor você pode salvá-lo como uma imagem no formato jpg. Já existe uma resposta de um usuário no StackOverflow sobre como fazer essa conversão de base64 para blob, segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/7028326).
3. A última opção é usar multipart/form-data, a diferença é que neste caso você precisa do objeto File da imagem ao invés do base64. Segue o [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formdata/) de um tutorial muito bom.

Comment: A ultima resposta (Ponto 3), deu certinho no meu caso! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Base64 url of image trimmed one without data:image/png;base64
string base64="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQE...";
// Naming the image
const date = new Date().valueOf();
let text = '';
const possibleText = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   text += possibleText.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *    possibleText.length));
}
// Replace extension according to your media type
const imageName = date + '.' + text + '.jpeg';
// call method that creates a blob from dataUri
const imageBlob = this.dataURItoBlob(base64);
const imageFile = new File([imageBlob], imageName, { type: 'image/jpeg' });


dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
   const byteString = window.atob(dataURI);
   const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
   const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
   for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
     int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: 'image/jpeg' });    
   return blob;
}
```